# How to set inheritance from my own Class to built-in Class

Tags: javascript

How to set inheritance from my own Class to built-in Class

We got big built-in class Image ( for example i'm using it inside Canvas to show an image ) .

```
img = new Image ()
img.onload = function () { .... }
```

I want that my image could have methods and properties of my own class Counter .

```
class Counter {
    constructor {
        this.orientation = orientation
    }
}
```

How can i set the inheritance of class Image from my class Counter ( of corse without overriding constructor of Image ) ?
Maybe it's a trivial question , but in all lessons that i saw , Child class was created and got inheritance from built-in classes and now i need reverse of that .
Also it could be wrong approach to solution . In this case i would be grateful if someone show me right ways , cause ' i don't know what i don't know'.

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you want to have instance of Counter class in your Image class and maybe wrap calls to counter methods with methods in Image class ? That is called composition. Inheritance is not always a right solution.

Comment: Composition ? Heard something . Maybe you got some simple example  ?

Comment: Yes.
For example you want to have methods of Counter inside Image. Create instance of Counter class in Image class :
    class Image {
           private Counter myCounter = new Counter();
           ... etc
          // Now you can access Counter method by calling it from Image
         callCounter() {
              return myCounter.count();
        }
}

That means that Counter is part of Image and you can use methods call from it, just wrap it up with Image method that will call Counter.
If we are talking design patterns it's close to Facade,

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't understood that you have Image class that is not yours. Then you can extend Image prototype with methods like this :
Image.prototype.callCounterMethod = function() { Counter counter = new Counter; return counter.count() }
This way you will extend Image prototype with methods that internally use Counter to perform some action and you can have properties too.

Comment: Read a bit about prototype inheritance overall and how you can extend prototypes of any built-in Javascript class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way - extend Image prototype with methods that will call Counter :

```
Image.prototype.imageCount = function() {
    let me = this;
    let counter = new Counter();
    return counter.count(me.numberOfImages);
}

// usage
let myImage = new Image();
myImage.numberOfImages = 42;
myImage.imageCount(); // will call counter
```

This way Counter methods are wrapped up inside Image class and part of Image class prototype.